# how to create tamil custom keyboard on android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

> I have no idea to create custom tamil keyboard.
>   give me some links or some code for creating tamil keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create :
Here is tut for the same [Link 1](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html) but you need to input the tamil input on code ..You need to HardCode the inputs of softKeyboard as shown in code

Comment: i did hardcode for tamil letters.but i made tamil keyboard but if i type that letters, it should make word based on the letters.but if i type ம and ூ in tamil keyboard that letters should be converted to மூ. but it shows like ம ூ.it is not converting to word from letters.in english keyboard what we type,it shows that letters.but in tamil keyboard we have to make word.so what can i do for converting word from that letters.

Comment: ok, there u need to check the cobinationation now and replace with the single words ...or need to research something but u will get it see this once http://google-input-tamil.software.informer.com/  &  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.sriandroid.telugu&hl=en

Comment: http://www.blogsolute.com/install-indian-regional-language-fonts-android-keyboard/21947/ refer this link you will get good idea @Aravi

Comment: More more query contact Venkat here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Comment: how to make android device to support tamil language.i made keyboard but it is not supporting tamil language.